# Laravel create if statement when img missing in array in blade

Tags: php, laravel

How to create `if` statement in laravel `blade` when my email with image missing in array ?
When email is not defined in array, laravel show error.

My goal is when email with image are defined in array show the image, if email isnt defined show custom jpg.

`my array`

```
$picture = array (
      'email1@email.com' => '1.jpg',
      'email2@email.com' => '2.jpg',
      'email3@email.com' => '3,jpg'
);
```

`blade`

```
<img src="{{ asset('/images/'.$picture[(Auth()->user()->mail_from)] ) }}" height="333" width="222" alt="" style="margin-left: 65px"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the null coalesce operator to check if that array key is set and use it or use a default:

```
$picture[Auth()->user()->mail_from] ?? 'custom.jpg'
```

You could use `Collection@get` as well:

```
collect($picture)->get(Auth()->user()->mail_from, 'custom.jpg');
```

Comment: try it with undefined email in array and got this error: ````Undefined index: email|Test@email.com```` i used your first code: ````{{ asset('/images/'.$picture[Auth()->user()->mail_from] ?? 'images/custom.jpg' ) }}````

Comment: ````<img src="{{ asset('/images/'.collect($picture)->get(Auth()->user()->mail_from, 'custom.jpg') ) }}" height="333" width="222" alt="" style="margin-left: 65px"/>```` works!